# Отправка Json запроса в контроллер

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Здравствуйте!
Проблема в том, что при указании url "`/Home/GetJson`" со страницы Home/Index
Данные приходят, а если такой же url объявить с любого другого контроллера, например `ExampleController`, то данные не приходят, т.к. "`Path/Example/Home/GetJson`" не существует, ошибка "`Uncaught reference error`".
Так выглядит скрипт:

```
function getBanner() {
        $.getJSON("/Home/GetBanner", null, setBanner);
    }
```

Нужно, чтобы функция getJSON обращалась всегда в /Home/Index из любого другого контроллера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте для этого в представлении класс [`UrlHelper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper(v=vs.108).aspx) и его методы для генерации ссылки на действие контроллера (например - [`UrlHelper.Action(string, string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd492758(v=vs.108).aspx))

Вот как должно получиться:

```
function getBanner() {
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetBanner", "Home")', null, setBanner);
}
```